# How to alter columns with ActiveRecord in Rails?

Tags: database, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3, migration

I'm new to ActiveRecord. I realized that I had forgotten to add a default value for a column in one of my tables. I want to create a migration to fix this, but I can't figure out how. Is there an alter_column method that you can call during migrations? If not, how can I do it?

EDIT: I just tried using change_column, but this causes an error like this:

-- change_column(:carts, :quantity, :integer, {:default=>1})
   -> 0.0097s
rake aborted!
An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can simply do a `change_table`:

```
change_table(:tablename) do |t|
   t.change :name, :string, :default => "something"
end
```

*edit*: in this case you can use [change_column_default](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/SchemaStatements.html#method-i-change_column_default)

Comment: That doesn't work in Rails 3. It gives me this error: 'SQLite3::SQLException: duplicate column name: quantity: ALTER TABLE "carts" ADD "quantity" integer DEFAULT 1'

Comment: `t.change` is the correct method to use not `t.column` as that tries to add a new column. I've updated the answer.